# Only getting service definition when uploading feature layer from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, feature-layer, service-definition

I have a point feature layer in ArcGIS Pro. Whenever I upload this layer to AGOL I only get to see the service definition. The feature layer itself is gone. Basically  I can't do much with only this service definition.

Though I can access this feature layer via more details, but whenever I am in a map I can't add this feature layer.

Anyone knows what this could be and how to solve it?

[image]

I tried it a few times.

Comment: What are the steps you followed to "upload" the layer top AGOL?

Comment: Click on the layer. Click sharing -> share as web layer. Filled in some of the required fields as usual. And then click on run

Comment: This is very strange. Do you get any errors from the upload process? It sounds like something has gone wrong in creating the service. I'd suspect ArcGIS Pro should tell you about it. Alternatively you might want to try changing the data you're using to see if you can narrow it down.

Comment: I have found a workaround. It had to do something with the coordinate system. I normally use RD New, but I changed it to WGS and it somehow worked. I have never had this problem. So it is still weird.